# Load a properties file in a servlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have a properties file in the WEB-INF with some properties that need to be used by my servlet (properties like a database password,...). What's the best way to load this file? Should I Override the init method of the servlet so that I only load the file once?

Thanks

Comment: I'm using Netbeans and JBoss AS7

Comment: Are these parameters specific only for one servlet or should they be also available for other servlets?

Comment: They will also be used by other servlets

Comment: Any reason why these are not context parameters in web.xml? Sounds like that's a good use case for it...

Comment: Since there will be a lot of parameters I'll prefer to have them in a separate file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not saying that this way is correct or anything since I don't work with JEE but from what I remember you can use `ServletContextListener` methods for this. Just implement it like

```
class ContextListenerImpl implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        //lets skip it for now
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {

        ServletContext sc = sce.getServletContext();

        //read parameter from properties and add it to servlet context attributes
        sc.setAttribute("yourParameterName", "value");
    }

}
```

You should be able to use it in any servlet via for instance

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    //...
    getServletContext().getAttribute("yourParameterName");
    //...
}
```

BTW value of attributes can hold also other objects, not only Strings.

Oh, and lets not forget to add this listener to your web application. Just add

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>full.name.of.ContextListenerImpl</listener-class>
</listener>
```

to your `web.xml` file.

Comment: Does this solution allow others servlets to access the same properties?

Comment: Yes, there should be only only one `ServletContext` for entire web application so `getServletContext()` should return same instance of this class in all servlets. It is also same instance we got in listener via  `sce.getServletContext();` so all servlets will be reading attributes from same `ServletContext`.